How to pass Query parameters into custom pipes in nestjs
I am trying to create two custom pipes ExcelToJsonPipe and JsonValidationPipe. First to transform the Excel file content into Json, and second is to validate that Json.
But the transform and validation logic depends on a query parameter which I am trying to pass in the constructor of these pipes.
@UsePipes(
        new JoiValidationPipe({
          param: getByIdValidations,
          query: uploadExcelQueryValidation,
        }),
      )
      @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
      @Post(':id/questions/uploadExcel')
      async createQuestionsByUploadExcel(
        @Param() params,
        @Query() query,
        @UploadedFile(new ExcelToJsonPipe(query), new JsonValidationPipe(query)) file: Express.Multer.File,
      ) {
        return this._genieJourneyService.generateQuestionsByUploadExcel(params.id, file);
      }

But this is one of the two similar errors I am getting:

error TS2552: Cannot find name 'query'. Did you mean 'Query'?
192     @UploadedFile(new ExcelToJsonPipe(query), new JsonValidationPipe(query)) file: Express.Multer.File

My question is: how can I pass the query to constructor of these pipes, please?
For more context I am providing some more details:
export const uploadExcelQueryValidation = Joi.object({
  gameFormat: Joi.string().valid(...Object.values(GenieGames))
}).unknown(false);

export class ExcelToJsonPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private readonly queryParams: any) {}
  async transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (!value) {
      throw new BadRequestException('No file uploaded');
    }

    // here is some logic to transform the value


  }

Thanks in advance. Any help in this will be appreciated.
